# If else not working within a loop and dos box closes before I can see any errors

Tags: batch-file

I have very little experiance of batch files and have cobbled this together from other files I have written.

The batch file will have a folder of images dropped over the icon and should carry out different resizing depending on the photo oriantation.

The dos window closes before I can read any errors.

If I have the convert or identify lines only ( one at a time ) within the loop it works but with the if else it fails. With the IF ELSE activated the opening parentheses after the DO does not highlight the closing parenteses in my text editor.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
REM @echo off

REM Read all the png images from the directory
FOR %%f IN (%1\*.png) DO (

REM Set the variable width to the image width
SET width=identify -format "%%[fx:w]" %%f

REM Set the variable height to the image height
SET height=identify -format "%%[fx:h]" %%f

REM Check if the photo is portrate or landscape and run the relavant code
IF %width% LSS %height% (
convert "%%f" -trim -resize x740 "modified/%%~nf.jpg" 
) ELSE (
convert "%%f" -trim -resize x740 -background blue -gravity center -extent 740x740 "modified/%%~nf.jpg" 
)
)

PAUSE
```

ERRORS:

```
C:\>REM @echo off

C:\>REM Read all the png images from the directory
( was unexpected at this time.

C:\>IF  LSS  (
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're in windows--you need to open the command prompt and run this script from there. That will stop the box from closing, and allow you to properly debug any errors.

Comment: Thanks jnunn I can see the errors now and have added then to the original post.

Comment: It's not seeing your %width% variable, which is interesting. I'm not versed enough on dos batch files to troubleshoot that. Try hardcoding width to something, to see if it picks it up then, like: `SET width=10` instead of `SET width=identify -format "%%[fx:w]"`

Comment: I just noticed as there is no image to get the dimension of on the identify line! Code modified above again but still no output. I will try your suggestions now.

Comment: No hard coding a variable still comes up with C:\>IF  LSS  ( I am wondering if the proble is before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, expand the argument and use blackquotes to evade error in spacenames.

And second, you can't set the output of a command into a variable in the way that you are trying to do it.
You need to get the output of the command with an FOR /F, no other way.

Try this:

(UPDATED)

1. Make sure you pass the correct argument to the script with \ slashes, not /

.

```
    @echo off

    Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :: Removes the last slash if given in argument %1
    Set "Dir=%~1"
    IF "%DIR:~-1%" EQU "\" (Set "Dir=%DIR:~0,-1%")

    :: Read all the png images from the directory

    FOR %%f IN ("%dir%\*.png") DO (

        :: Set the variable width to the image width
        For /F %%# in ('identify -format "%%[fx:w]" "%%f"') Do (SET /A "width=%%#")

        :: Set the variable height to the image height
        For /F %%# in ('identify -format "%%[fx:h]" "%%f"') Do (SET /A "height=%%#")

        :: Create the output folder if don't exist
        MKDIR ".\modified" 2>NUL

        :: Check if the photo is portrate or landscape and run the relavant code
        IF !width! LSS !height! (
            convert "%%f" -trim -resize x740 "modified\%%~nf.jpg" 
        ) ELSE (
            convert "%%f" -trim -resize x740 -background blue -gravity center -extent 740x740 "modified\%%~nf.jpg" 
            )
        )

    PAUSE&EXIT
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and I have tried your code but I still get an error:C:\>C:\Users\Anthony\Pictures\batch_tests\sweden_1.bat C:\Users\Anthony\Pictures
\batch_tests\TESTS
( was unexpected at this time.
C:\>   It still looks like the ( after the DO is a problem

Comment: not, the problem should be in the "(" at the comparation of width and height line, if one of the vars is empty then gets an error of "(", i've updated the code above to let you check if all is good again, try it and comment.

Comment: I am afraid I am still getting a ( was unexpected at this time. No other output. I use Notepad++ as a text editor and the ( after the DO is green and the last ) which ties up with the one after DO is black and neither of them change to red to indicate a pair as they do for the other pairs of ( )

Comment: tell me where i can found the identify tool and then I can resolve this for you (but see my last comment again). EDIT: ok i've found imagemagick, wait a minutes for my reply

Comment: After your last edit I still get the ( was unexpected at this time. Off to bed now so will check back tomorrow.

Comment: I've updated my answer, i've tested the code with png files, all good,solved :), goodnight

Comment: +1, but I've have never heard the term "blackquote". The quote terms I'm familiar with are: " = double quote, ' = single quote, \` = back quote or back tick.

Comment: maybe its a linguistic error, I will mean double quotes. remember to accept an answer if your problem was resolved, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the great piece of code Elektro Hacker. I would never have known what to search for to write it. LSS works the oposite way to what I expected and appart from that works great.